# WebHttpRequest fails (500) while postman successfully runs the web GET request

Tags: c#, ajax, web-services, httpwebrequest, postman

I try to get a specific value from a specific site...

the site periodically updating the value using an Ajax call to 
https://www.plus500.co.il/api/LiveData/FeedUpdate?instrumentId=19

(you can Navigate to the address and see you get the XML response.)

using Postman:
sending

```
GET /api/LiveData/FeedUpdate?instrumentId=19 HTTP/1.1
Host: www.plus500.co.il
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: f823c87d-3edc-68ce-e1e7-02a8fc68be7a
```

I get a valid Json Response...

Though, when i try it from C#:

```
var webRequest = WebRequest.CreateHttp(@"https://www.plus500.co.il/api/LiveData/FeedUpdate?instrumentId=19");
webRequest.Method = "GET";
using (var response = webRequest.GetResponse())
{...}
```

The request Fails with Error-Code 403 (Forbidden)

when adding:

```
webRequest.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/68.0.3440.84 Safari/537.36";
```

The request Fails with Error-Code 500 (Internal Server Error)

**Addition (Edit)**

I also initiate with

```
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate { return true; };
        ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 |
                                   SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 |
                                   SecurityProtocolType.Tls |
                                   SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3;
```

Also, I Tried Setting a CookieContainer, but the result is the same 500.

Why is Postman/Chrome Successfuly querying this API while C# Webrequest do not?
What is the difference?

Comment: You need to explicitly set `ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;` A validation callback is not required. Also, you should provide a CookieContainer (it will set 2 cookies). If a sample code is needed, let me know.

Comment: @Jimi I did set a cookie container but it was same. and Forgot to show i enabled all Tls1, Tls2, Ssl.

Comment: Is there something else that is not shown here? What is needed for this connection (tested by exclusion): Tls1.2, a User-Agent header, Automatic decompression (`.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate;`) coupled with a `Accept-encoding` header. A `CookieContainer` could be useful (on your side), but is not required. Neither is the Server Certificate validation callback (with the connection address provided, might be needed for a different access level). You didn't say whether there's a Proxy in between.

Comment: The Accept-encoding header: `webRequest.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.AcceptEncoding, "gzip, deflate;q=0.8");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, the reason that this is failing is because of the headers being included in the client request from postman by default, though not from the C# request.

Using a program like Fiddler (https://www.telerik.com/fiddler) you can watch the request to see that the headers from the postman request are:

```
Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8    
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br    
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9    
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/68.0.3440.84 Safari/537.36
```

Yet from C# are just

```
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36
```

Filling in the extra client request headers like this allows it to go through fine:

```
webRequest.Accept = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8";
webRequest.Headers.Add("Accept-Encoding", "gzip deflate,br");
webRequest.Headers.Add("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.9");
```

Comment: It looks like the headers required are the `User-Agent` to avoid a 403 and the `Accept-Encoding` to avoid the 500.

Comment: this seem to work... i just need to figure the return streem. Thanks

Comment: Thanks, It works great now.
didn't know Postman add headers that it doesn't show.
Thanks again